# Int won't increment by 1

Tags: c#, int, increment

I'm trying to increment the value of an int: `counter` by 1 each time the `stakebtn` is pressed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
private void stakebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int counter = 0;
  counter++;
  currentstakes.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

However, this only works one time- the `currentstakes` label will not go above 1.

Is anyone able to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are setting it to 0 every time the button is clicked and then incrementing it.  Of course it will never go above 1.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  You set counter to zero, then increment it by 1.  What value would you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, it will increase only one time, declare it outside your click,

```
int counter = 0;

private void stakebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  counter++;
  currentstakes.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it to zero every time before you increment it, move the counter declaration outside the method:

```
int counter = 0;
private void stakebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  counter++;
  currentstakes.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```